# How to select data using table/column names stored in a table? Dynamically building SQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table that shows events and vehicles associated with those events:

```
id | model | colour     | cargo
--------------------------------------------
1 | vw       | red      | tomatoes
2 | bmw      | red      | golf clubs
```

I would like to have a table that I can use to manage alerts. There is a column that represents strings to check for, another column that shows which column/table it is applied to and some text that describes the alert:

```
id | column_name    | check_string     | alert_string
--------------------------------------------
1 | my_table.colour | red              | 'Vehicle is red'
2 | my_table.cargo  | [sport,club]     | 'Vehicle is carrying sports goods'
```

or possibly:

```
id | column_name    | check_string     | alert_string
--------------------------------------------
1 | my_table.colour | red              | 'Vehicle is red'
2 | my_table.cargo  | sport            | 'Vehicle is carrying sports goods'
3 | my_table.cargo  | club             | 'Vehicle is carrying sports goods'
```

I would like to have a query that I can run that would return all the alerts that apply to that row:

```
id | alert_text
--------------------------------------------
1 | ['Vehicle is red']
2 | ['Vehicle is red', 'Vehicle is carrying sports goods']
```

The way I was doing this was building up SQL commands in Python and running them against the database but this becomes a burden as the number of rules grow or variables need to be changed/updated (suddenly we don't care about red cars but are very concerned with blue cars).

```
SELECT id, 'Vehicle is red' as alert_text FROM my_table 
WHERE my_table.colour = 'red';

SELECT id, 'Sports goods' as alert_text FROM my_table 
WHERE my_table.cargo in ['sport', 'club'];

SELECT <many other rules>;
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is it worth building a DB table that can dynamically point to a column, strings to check in that column and then alert text associated with the rule? Should I even be using SQL for this problem?

I've got a feeling that SQL is maybe not the right tool for this job but I don't know what I don't know...

Comment: What is the data type of `cargo`?  Why are you storing multiple values in one column instead of using a junction/association table?

Comment: cargo is a string, it is generally multiple words in no specific order or structure. Example "3 boxes of ABC and no hazardous cargo, 2 barrels of ammunition". I need to check for specific things such as "ammunition" in the cargo description. I might need to do multiple checks on a single row. In the questions example I could just separate "sport" and "clubs" into 2 rows instead of one.

Comment: You must have a front end tool to your database that could easily be used to fulfill such a request without a problem. You could also keep all your queries in views and run each view as needed without typing sql each time.

Comment: That's what I'm asking about... What front-end tool should I be using to manage these kind of requests. Should I store the alerts table as-is but do the alert-text building in pandas? Is there a way to do this in SQL? Is it "correct" to do this in SQL? What is best practice for managing dynamic, rule based, periodic queries?

Comment: It doesn't sound like it'd be that horrible to do without any kind of special front-end tool just using SQL and maybe a few pgPL/SQL stored procedures. Focus on normalizing the data (the "or possibly" form above will work better with SQL than your original form) and add your dynamic table that can point to the appropriate alerts. It'd be a bit more work up front but ultimately be robust and easily adjusted for new checks.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL code would allow you to have a DB table of any size for both Events and Alerts

```
Declare @vSQL nvarchar(Max)
Declare @vColumnName nvarchar(25)
Declare @vCheckString nvarchar(25)
Declare @vAlertString nvarchar(50)

Declare vCursor CURSOR For
  Select [column_name], [check_string], [alert_string] From vehicle_alerts

  Open vCursor;
  Fetch Next From vCursor Into @vColumnName, @vCheckString, @vAlertString

  --Make global temp table from source then delete contents.  
  --Ensures field lengths are as large as the largest value in the temp table (Not the most efficient but it works)
  Select id, alert_string INTO ##alerts From vehicle_alerts
  Delete From ##alerts  

  While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  --Loop through alerts and interrogate your events using the LIKE operator
  Begin
     Set @vSQL = 'INSERT INTO ##alerts Select id, '''+@vAlertString+''' As [Alert] From vehicle_events Where ' + @vColumnName + ' Like ''%' + @vCheckString + '%'''
     Execute (@vSQL)
     Fetch Next From vCursor Into @vColumnName, @vCheckString, @vAlertString
  End;

  --Use STUFF to combine the alert strings by id
  Select id,STUFF((Select ',' + [alert_string] From ##alerts Where id = a.id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Tmp 
  From ##alerts AS a
  Group By id

  Drop Table ##alerts
  Close vCursor
  Deallocate vCursor
```

Comment: That doesn't look like standard SQL. Is that MS SQL Server? The question was tagged for PostgreSQL, so that may not work.

Comment: This is from MS SQL 2014